# How can I send packets with intervals in lognormal distribution in OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++

I want to generate packets in lognormal distribution in OMNeT++. I tried:

```
**.node_1.AppSource[0].sendInterval =  lognormal(0.5,0.7)
```

However, it gave the error:

> Cannot evaluate parameter 'sendInterval': Cannot convert unit none to 's' (second)

I see that only uniform, exponential, normal and truncnormal distributions have SimTime version. The other distributions like lognormal are in SIM_API double, so they don't have a unit.

How can I send packets with intervals in lognormal distribution in OMNeT++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true that lognormal does not accept a unit in arguments.
However, one may use the following workaround to obtain random value with the unit:

```
**.node_1.AppSource[0].sendInterval = lognormal(0.5, 0.7)*1s
```